# can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker

Trying to get started with python & Docker, managed to get Docker working with a PHP example but struggling to get it working with a python file.

I am trying to get a simple hello world docker container running to simply print "Hello world"

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

## app.py

```
def hello():
    return print("hello world")
hello()
```

## I have run the following commands

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -p 80:80 test
```

Expected result: containerised app running on port 80

Actual result:python: can't open file './app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: app.py is in the app/ directory or it's outside?

Comment: try `COPY app.py .`

Comment: Directory is the following:
Docker ls
Dockerfile, src (folder)
------
app.py sits in the src folder

Comment: You might try `docker run --rm -it test sh` to launch your image (`test`) running a shell (`sh`) instead of the Dockerfile CMD.  That would let you see what’s inside the image that’s built, and try running `python app.py` directly.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, the directory structure seems to be

```
Dockerfile
src/
   app.py
```

In this case, the `CMD` statement in your `Dockerfile` should be:

```
CMD [ "python", "src/app.py" ]
```

This is because of your `app.py` residing inside `src` folder with respect to the mentioned `WORKDIR`.

Comment: @GinoMempin: OP is copying everything from current directory to the `/app` folder of the container. `COPY . /app`. So, OP doesn't need to `COPY src .` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`WORKDIR` makes any subsequent commands run within that work dir you specified.
So, the next line `COPY . /app` will copy files to this directory `./app/app` not `./app`

Comment: If the right-hand side of `COPY` is an absolute path, that container path is used directly without considering `WORKDIR`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, although I used `docker-compose up`, but I believe the essence is the same, meaning that it couldn't find the file I wanted to run. I fixed the error by **changing the file path** to `python /app/manage.py` instead of `python manage.py`. The corrected `Dockerfile` code is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
CMD pwd && ls -l && python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues as you.
I ran `docker compose up` always resulted in a similar error as you. When I had a correct setup it still failed due to an already-built container and downloaded images.
Here is how I solved it:

- I removed my already-built container along with the images.
- Then I removed everything in my folder EXCEPT for app.py and requirements.txt
- Then I ran docker init (and followed the python instructions)
- And then `docker compose` worked

`docker init` auto-generates `compose.yaml`, `Dockerfile`, `README.Docker.md`, `.dockerignore`. I recommend having a look at those.